# How many people are needed in a team to ensure one is at work?

Tags: probability, coupon-collector

How does one estimate the probability that at least one person from a team is in the office during working hours (9 am - 5 pm)? My assumptions are:

- There are 3 people in the team
- There are 253 working days in the year
- Each person has 38 working days out of the office (annual leave + meetings)
- Days out of the office are randomly taken
- When not out of the office the person is available (ignore sick leave etc.)

The question is a real life question that is needed to work out the amount of time that the office is not staffed. The extension to the question above is:
How many people are needed to increase the probability to say 95%?

I have looked at the coupon-collector's problem, but I have little experience in calculating probabilities and so I am unsure how to apply it to this problem. What are the steps required?

Comment: Is this a problem from a book ? We will need to make a lot of quite unrealistic assumptions to solve a simplified model, e.g. everyone takes leave, goes out randomly whenever she/he wants, without any planning.

Comment: In fact, it is much simpler to compute the average amount of time the office is not staffed (see drhab's hints) than it is to compute the probability that it's staffed every day.  But the former does imply an estimate of the latter, and the estimate should be pretty accurate for the 95% probability range you're interested in.

Comment: @SarahM Even though you don't have enough points to comment on drhab's answer, you should be able to comment on your own post, or in this case it probably makes sense to edit your question to give more detail on what it is you're having trouble calculating.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**:

- Calculate the probability that a fixed person is working on a fixed day.
- Calculate the probability that none of the $3$ persons are working on a fixed day.
- Calculate the probability that at least one of the $3$ persons is working on a fixed day.
- Do the same for $n$ instead of $3$ to get some view on how this depends on the size of the team.
- Let  $X_i=1$ if at least one person is working on day $i$  and $X_i=0$ otherwise. Then $X_1+\cdots+X_{253}$ equals the number of days that at least one is at work. Find its expectation and draw conclusions about the fraction you mention.

Comment: How do you calculate the probability that none of the 3 persons are working on a fixed day from these hints?